# Django: Can I have an app in a sub folder of another app?

Tags: django

I tried to put an app inside another app (Outer one is a facade into the inner one so it made sense to locate them that way), and it doesn't create a table for the model in that inner app. Is this normal? (the app is installed, and registered with the admin)

Comment: Not sure, but you might need to add the inner app to the list of `INSTALLED_APPS` as `'outer_app_name.inner_app_name'`.

Comment: Yea, it works. I had a damn syntax error is why it didn't work, but id didn't catch the error during syncdb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django loads models by importing the `models` module of every package in the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. For example, with an `INSTALLED_APPS` setting of `('django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.comments', 'spam.ham', and 'eggs')`, Django will import models from `django.contrib.admin.models`, `django.contrib.comments.models`, `spam.ham.models`, and `eggs.models`.

If you are only listing your outer app in `INSTALLED_APPS` (we'll assume it's named `eggs`), then only the models from `eggs.models` are being imported and created. To get the models installed from your inner app, you will need to add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` as well, like `eggs.inner_app`, so that `eggs.inner_app.models` will get imported. (To facilitate foreign keys, I'm pretty sure that if you import models from one app into another's `models.py` file, only the models defined in the `models.py` file being scanned get created.)